# Oracle sql how join works for below scenario

Tags: sql, oracle

B with one column empid.

```
table A
1
1
1

Table B
1
1
```

after doing inner join it gives me 6 records .Please help me how join works on this

Answer (score 1):

If you add more data you'll get a better idea:

```
TableA
empid,other
1,A
1,B
1,C

TableB
empid,other
1,Y
1,Z

SELECT * FROM A INNER JOIN B ON a.empid=b.empid
```

Produces:

```
1,A,1,Y
1,A,1,Z
1,B,1,Y
1,B,1,Z
1,C,1,Y
1,C,1,Z
```

Voila, 6 rows - every row in A that has column empid=1 is joined to every row in B that has column empid=1

You'll notice that the rows from A are each present twice (there are two A, two B, two C) and the rows from B are present 3 times (there are three Y, three Z). The A rows are present 2 times because they all match to 2 rows from b. The B rows are all present 3 times because they match to 3 rows from A